# Highcharts - Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | GradientColorObject | PatternObject | undefined'.ts(2322)

Tags: highcharts, angular13

While creating a simple pie chart in Angular 13, getting following error message.
Want to assign null value to borderColor but it is showing this error. Assigned colors in series.
[image]

Comment: What is unclear from the error message?

Comment: As, assigned different colors for the pie chart in series don't want to assign any color to borderColor property. But here it is giving an error. Tried with undefined but not sure what what assign for null.

Comment: "Tried with undefined" - did you? That _would_ be a valid value given the type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, it is valid. Was trying with  ' null | undefined ' . Anyways thank you.

Comment: `null | undefined` looks more like a type than a value! It evaluates to `0`, which as a `number` is also none of the allowed types.

Answer (score 1):

`borderColor: undefined` works here.

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: '99%',
            borderWidth: 40,
            borderColor: undefined,
            slicedOffset: 20,
            dataLabels: {
                connectorWidth: 0
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).